# Which string variables in mysql support utf-8?

Tags: mysql, character-set, utf-8, encoding

I have a table that stores string from a user and is displayed in a web form.
But as I see when the user inputs e.g. in a language of cyrilic alphabet (I assume is UTF-8) garbage are displayed back.
I did a show create table and I saw that the table is defined as LATIN-1 and the column that stores the string is defined as TEXT.
I am not clear on what type of data does TEXT stores. Is it only for ASCII? Should I be using a different data type? Which would be the most appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to specify a character set of UTF8 on the table schema.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-syntax.html

Depending on your needs you can specify table defaults which then apply to all unspecified text columns (char/varchar/text) or you can specify on a per column level.

You'll also need to have your applications to specify a UTF-8 character encoding.  The specifics on how to do this will depend on the language you are using.

Comment: And the applicaton's [client connection to the server](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-connection.html) needs to be correctly configured to support utf8.

Comment: So how could i alter the text column to support UTF-8? Does it now support only LATIN-1? Also how could I alter the table so that it supports UTF-8? Also if I do such an alter are the existing data corrupted?